# What could the expression "ナンパされた" mean in english?

Tags: expressions

ナンパ - seducer, ladies' man, playboy
された - passive form + past tense of する

Answer (score 8):

Depends on the situation but the possible meanings are:

"I got hit on."

"I got picked up."

"A guy tried to pick me up."

The reason that I said the meaning depended on the situation is that the phrase 「ナンパされた。」 says nothing about the result -- that is whether the guy was successful or not.

In the original 「ナンパされた。」, the unmentioned subject would usually be "I", "She", "They", etc.  It is the woman/women who got hit on.

Extra Info: When a woman tries to pick up a man, that is called 「[逆]{ぎゃく}ナンパ」 -- 「逆ナン」 for short if you want to sound more street.